# React Hooks: State Is Not Updating in Function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have spent several hours trying to fix this issue with no luck. I have a reusable component that starts with a state of any empty object, the object is given a series of properties based off of props, and then based on user input on each set of radio buttons will show a child component.

Unfortunately, the function that is supposed to update the state that will then trigger whether the user sees the child component is not working.

I believe the issue is in my editDisplay function. Currently when I click one of the radio buttons the new object that should become the new state is logged to the console correctly, but when I use React Devtools to inspect the page, I see that state is not updating. That being said, I could see a case where I am misunderstanding useEffect, and perhaps useEffect is running each time editDisplay is running. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {Form} from 'react-bootstrap'
import RatingInput from './RatingInput'

export default function MembershipForm({inputs, name, record, setRecord}) {

  const [display, setDisplay] = useState({})

  useEffect(()=>{
      inputs.forEach(input => {
          var newDisplay = display
          newDisplay[name+input]=false
          setDisplay(newDisplay)})
  },[])

    const editDisplay = (input, visible) => {
        var newDisplay =display
          newDisplay[name+input]=visible
          console.log(newDisplay)
          setDisplay(newDisplay)
    }

    const questions=inputs.map(input => {
        return (
            <div key={name+input}>
                <Form.Group>
                    <Form.Label className='mx-2'>Do you have a {name} {input} Rating?</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Check inline label='Yes' value={true} name={name+input} type='radio' className = 'mx-2' onClick ={() =>{editDisplay(input, true)}} />
                    <Form.Check inline label='No' value ={false} name={name+input}  type='radio' className = 'mx-2' defaultChecked onClick = {() =>{editDisplay(input, false)}}  />
                </Form.Group>
                {display[name+input] && <RatingInput input={input}/>}
                
            </div >
        )
    })

    return (
        <div className='ml-3'>
            {questions}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 const editDisplay = (input, visible) => {
        var newDisplay = display
          newDisplay[name+input]=visible
          console.log(newDisplay)
          setDisplay(newDisplay)
    }
```

You should perform react state update in an *immutable way*.
What you are doing above is you are mutating existing state variable (that assignment on first line doesn't add much: `newDisplay` refers to same object as `display`). In such case react might not detect change. Do this instead:

```
    var newDisplay = { ... display };
```